# Spring Integration + Spring Boot Actuator Endpoints not showing up

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have been trying to learn more about Spring Boot and I would like to add the Actuator endpoints to my test Spring integration/Spring Boot project.  However, it is a plain, CLI Spring integration project--there are no current REST or web services.  I'd ideally like to add the ability to view the endpoints with a browser while the jar is running from the command line.

I have been looking through the tutorials and I'm not finding a lot on adding it to a regular project, rather than a web project.

I've added the dependencies (spring-boot-actuator), and can see the endpoints from the jconsole, but I never see a connection to a port on my system (using netstat) and never can navigate there.

Is there a tutorial or something that can show me how to have REST endpoints with a CLI project?

Thank you

newbo

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor and manage your application using `JMX` instead. See the [documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-jmx.html).

If you use IntelliJ IDEA, hit `CTRL+Space` in an `application.properties` file to see a lot of `JMX` properties ready for you, one of them being:

`endpoints.jmx.enabled=true` (true is the default value)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html), in order to show the endpoint user need to have **ACTUATOR** role.If you need to access without having the role you need to add the following value to application.properties:

```
management.security.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if it isn't a web project, no tomcat servlet will be embedded, therefor you wont be able to browse the actuator endpoints over `http`

Insert dependency `spring-boot-starter-web` into your project and it will probably work.